# Почему не сработала директива Angular JS после изменения значений в Service?

Tags: angularjs

Сейчас написана такая директива:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['CounterNotificationService', function(CounterNotificationService) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                transclude: true,
                scope: {},
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.CounterNotificationService = CounterNotificationService.getCounter();
                },
                templateUrl: 'myDirective.html'
            };
        }])
```

Она имеет зависимость от сервиса `CounterNotificationService` и возвращает в переменную `$scope.CounterNotificationService` результат от функции `getCounter()` сервиса.

HTML выглядит так:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective.html">
    {{CounterNotificationService}}
    </script>
    <div my-directive></div>
```

Сейчас директива отрабатывает своё, но если в контроллере вызвать изменение значений в сервисе:

```
CounterNotificationService.setCounterValue('messages', 6);
```

То директива не получает новые значения в строке:

```
$scope.CounterNotificationService = CounterNotificationService.getCounter();
```

Соответственно в шаблоне HTML так же не меняются значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `CounterNotificationService.getCounter()` возвращает примитив, то есть число, строчку, булево выражение? Если да, то попробуйте возвращать объект с полем, в котором будет хранится ваше значение и в своей директиве будете обращаться примерно как `$scope.CounterNotificationService.value`. Объект разумеется должен быть проинициализирован в сервисе.

Comment: Метод возвращает объект  `{messages : 0, notif : 0}`

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, пример на jsfiddle или более удобный для Вас сервис. Меня смутил тот факт, что Вы используете сервис в контроллере предварительно не "проинжектив" его.